# ACPI shutdown with locked user session

Tags: virtualbox, shutdown, lock-screen, acpi

I try to backup an Ubuntu VirtualBox guest. VirtualBox `save state` is not a solution, because it's VirtualBox version dependent. So I need to do an ACPI shudown (with VirtualBox `acpipowerbutton`). **The problem is that, the ACPI shutdown for Ubuntu seems to work if no user session exists or user session is not locked**.

What I have done so far is writing a (Windows cmd) script to acpi shutdown (`acpipowerbutton`) VirtualBox the Linux guests (Ubuntu and MINT). Works perfect, but not with locked guest system user sessions.

Again: ACPI for unlocked sessions works already. But not for locked sessions. `systemctl status acpid.service` tells me 'active (running)'. So I think the ACPI service itself is existing and working but needs to be configured?

Is there a way to **change settings** within Ubuntu **to allow an ACPI shutdown for locked sessions?**

Or maybe is there any "force" option in VirtualBox to do an ACPI shutdown for locked Ubuntu guests?

Comment: We can answer this question for Ubuntu since OP is using Ubuntu. The information that Mint is also being used might even help find an answer. There's no reason to close this as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to install the `acpid` service to accomplish this goal. Here are the full set of steps to follow:

0. Open a Terminal (if not already open)
1. Install the `acpid` service:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install acpid
   ```
2. Configure `acpid` to run a script called `doevents.sh` on events:

   ```
   $ sudo echo -e 'event=.*\naction=/etc/acpi/doevents.sh %e' > /etc/acpi/events/anything
   ```

   ***Note:** The file name can be anything. If you'd rather use something other than* `doevents.sh`, *feel free to substitute it.*
3. Create the `doevents.sh` file:

   ```
   $ sudo echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n\ncase "$1" in\nbutton/power)\ncase "$2" in\nPBTN) shutdown -h now ;;\nesac\nesac\n' > /etc/acpi/doevents.sh
   $ sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/doevents.sh
   ```
4. Restart the `acpid` service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart acpid.service
   ```
5. Simulate a power-button press on the VM. It should gracefully shut down.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks Matigo. But I think it's not a solution because ACPI already works with unlocked user sessions (I edited my question to make it clearer). So probably I need to configure it, not installing it .. right?

Comment: I just tried ".. status aspid.service", it says "active (running)" already.